# Is "rewardist" a real word/profession?

Tags: meaning, neologisms

There's a new TV show called [Tracker](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt13875494/) about a man who goes around the country helping people find missing loved ones. Rather than describing himself as a private investigator, he says he's a "rewardist" -- he takes jobs where a reward has been offered, and his fee is the reward if he's successful.

I've searched a number of online dictionaries, ranging from the full OED to Wiktionary and Urban Dictionary, but none of them have this word. Is this a new word the creators coined to describe him? It doesn't seem to be a common word in the TV show's universe, he gets funny reactions when he uses it with other people.

The TV show is based on a series of books. I looked up the first book, [The Never Game](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0525535942), at Amazon.com. The synopsis describes him as a "reward seeker". If anyone has read the books, does he use the "rewardist" term there, or was it created specifically for the TV version?

Comment: A bounty hunter by any other name? Styling as a 'rewardist' implies that he cares about those offering the bounty.

Comment: Seems to be part of the character's eccentricity to make up a word. He finds missing persons using the literal tracking skills of indigenous hunters. He is not a bounty hunter who finds wanted criminals.

Comment: Yes, he's motivated by altruism (like The Fugitive, The Incredible Hulk, and other shows about wanderers who help out), but in this case we find out how he actually makes money.

Comment: I think  you know the answer. If he uses the word and it is nowhere else, one can conclude that he coined it.

Comment: It's a protologism rather than a neologism at the moment.

Comment: @YosefBaskin   Where is it written that 'bounty hunter' needs to refer to the hunting of criminals? That surely was the original meaning, and how would using the same term here not be appropriate?

Comment: [Wikipedia: A bounty hunter ... captures fugitives or criminals for a commission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounty_hunter). In the show, "He is not a bounty hunter who finds wanted criminals."